# M3 pro and xcode rosetta vs silicon destinations

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode15, rosetta

i recently upgraded from intel macbook pro to m3 pro. i am facing issue that **my xcode project is not running without rosetta simulator enabled**, i am not sure why and what are bad points or negatives if this is how it will work. i tried this with new project, that runs on apple silicon simulators. but older one does not work.
any help would be appreciated. [image]

There are not VALID_ARCHS flags as well, which came in search to find a solution. any help?